# Why did System.String[] appear as the output from printing 2d array?

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

Using this, I'm trying to print a list of the contents of players.text
I know that the foreach loop will print it just fine if the Console.Writeline 
is used. But I'm attempting to manipulate the data in particular ways later, and need it split using the indicated delimiter.

However, with the given code all I get is a repeated System.String[] printout.

I've done a search or two and most of what I've found has to do with one part or the other, I haven't found any information on how to use them together.

```
string[] playerFile = File.ReadAllLines("players.txt");

foreach (string s in playerFile)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(s);
    string[] playerStuff = s.Split(';');
    Console.WriteLine(playerStuff);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

I realize it's a simplistic question. But often, for me at least, it's missing the obvious that drives me the most crazy.

Thanks in advance.

Player;Team;POS;HR;RBI;AVG
Abreu, J;CWS;1B;30;101;0.29
Altuve, J;HOU;2B;15;66;0.313
Andrus, E;TEX;SS;7;62;0.258
Arenado, N;COL;3B;42;130;0.287
Aybar, E;LAA;SS;3;44;0.27

The above is the first few lines of the input.

Basically, I want it to look just like that, minus the semicolons. Formatting will come later.

Attempting to add a second foreach, such as was suggested below, the code looked like this:

`foreach (string s in playerFile)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(s);
                string[] playerStuff = s.Split(';');
                foreach (string player in playerStuff)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(player);
                }
            }`

This resulted in EACH piece of information getting it's own line. I follow the logic of why it did that, but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Why not just print out the `s`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what would be in playerStuff and how you would like it to print to the console?

Comment: This is the first 3 lines of the file. 
I want it to print without the semicolons, in a listed manner. The formatting I can take care of later with a separate method, I'm sure.

`Player;Team;POS;HR;RBI;AVG`
`Abreu, J;CWS;1B;30;101;0.29`
`Altuve, J;HOU;2B;15;66;0.313`

I can't just print the s because I need to be able to rearrange the list of players based on the stats they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting the output that you are is because it is trying to write the `Array` object  to the console; and it doesn't know how to handle it, so it is just printing out the `Type` of the object that it is trying to write out.

You need to do another `foreach` or something similar on playerStuff.

```
string[] playerFile = File.ReadAllLines("players.txt");

foreach (string s in playerFile)
{
    //Console.WriteLine(s);
    string[] playerStuff = s.Split(';');

    //Inner foreach that writes out each entry of the array
    foreach(var item in playerStuff)
    {
         Console.Write(item + " ");
    }
    Console.Write(Environment.NewLine);
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

OR even simpler

```
string[] playerFile = File.ReadAllLines("players.txt");

foreach (string s in playerFile)
{
     Console.WriteLine(s.Replace(';', ' '));
}
Console.ReadKey();
```

OR a one liner

```
string[] playerFile = File.ReadAllLines("players.txt");

playerFile.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Replace(';', ' ')));

Console.ReadKey();
```

Sample output image for all 3 of the above solutions:
[image]

[Console.WriteLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swx4tc5e(v=vs.110).aspx) docs for reference

[String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts(v=vs.110).aspx) docs for reference

Comment: This, or if you want to program 'fancily' `playerStuff.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x))`

Comment: I attempted to edit as suggested with this:

` foreach (string s in playerFile)
            {
                //Console.WriteLine(s);
                string[] playerStuff = s.Split(';');
                foreach (string player in playerStuff)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(player);
                }
            }
`
And ended up getting each element of each line posted on it's own line. Logically I see how that happened, but i'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: @RonR Can you add what your input is and what your expected output is and what your actual output is to the question?

Comment: @RonR I think my updated answer will get you closer to where you want to be; then you can worry about formatting.

Comment: The output of each player with the above code. Still puts each on it's own line. 
`Abreu, J`

`CWS`

`1B`  

`30`

`101`

`0.29`

Comment: If that is not correct; what is the issue / what are you expecting?

Comment: I want the information for each player to be on one line.

Comment: Sorry @drneel . I had the line with (item + " ") as a WriteLine instead of a Write

That was my issue. It prints the way desired now. THanks for the help. Formatting and manipulation are next for me.

Comment: @RonR If this solution solved your problem please upvote / accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a method call to compile the compiler has to figure out what you want to do and here, in particular, there are many overloads to the `Console.WriteLine` method. An "overload" basically means that there are several definitions of `Console.WriteLine`, all taking different types of parameters.

If the compiler can find an overload that takes exactly what you're trying to pass it, in this case `string[]`, then good, that's the overload that will be called.

If not then it will take "the next best thing", if at all possible.

Let's list all the overloads to `Console.WriteLine`:

```
WriteLine() 
WriteLine(Boolean)  
WriteLine(Char) 
WriteLine(Char[])   
WriteLine(Char[], Int32, Int32) 
WriteLine(Decimal)  
WriteLine(Double)   
WriteLine(Int32)    
WriteLine(Int64)    
WriteLine(Object)   
WriteLine(Single)   
WriteLine(String)   
WriteLine(String, Object)   
WriteLine(String, Object, Object)   
WriteLine(String, Object, Object, Object)   
WriteLine(String, Object, Object, Object, Object)   
WriteLine(String, Object[]) 
WriteLine(UInt32)   
WriteLine(UInt64)
```

Now, all of these will be able to accept a `string[]` except one:

```
WriteLine(Object)
```

This particular overload will simply call `.ToString()` on whatever it is passed.

Since a string array does not have a `ToString` implementation that looks at the contents of the array, or anything like that, the basic `System.Object.ToString()` method that every type inherits is used, and this simply returns the full name of the type as a string, which is basically `System.String[]`.

So that's why the code compiles, and also why it doesn't do what you expect it to do.

The question is, what *do* you expect it to do?

If you wanted it to output all the strings as a comma-separated set of values on each line you can do this:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", playerStuff));
```

If you simply wanted to concatenate all the strings and put nothing between them, replace the `", "` in the above statement with `""` or `string.Empty`:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(string.Empty, playerStuff));
```